# How to recover the stored value in the preferences libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My save:

```
   static final String PREFS_NAME = "ScoreGame";
Preferences preferences;
```

one variable temp
to output to the Class A

```
**Preferences preferences;**
     int tempGameScore = 0;//class B
    int dropsGatchered = 0; 

     **in create**


    preferences =  Gdx.app.getPreferences(Drop.PREFS_NAME);
```

in game scene i make this , class B

```
  if ((raindrop.y < 0) && !(index >= 15)) {

            iter.remove();
            game.tempGameScore = game.dropsGatchered;
            game.preferences.putInteger("score", game.tempGameScore);
            game.preferences.flush();
            game.dropsGatchered = 0;

            stopGame();
        }
```

**Class C**
I get the value and draw on the screen

```
@Override
public void create() {

    game.tempGameScore = game.preferences.getInteger("score");


}



textFont.draw(game.batch, " " + game.tempGameScore, (Drop.WIDTH / 2) - 55,
                    (Drop.HEIGHT / 2) + 50);
```

**When I close the app that my speed is lost and I want her to recover their variable game.tempGameScore**

Comment: Have you read the docs? (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) As stated you can obtain a value with the "get" method of the Preferences object (String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name stored")).

Comment: @josemgu91
Yes, I have read the documentation.
I do so and get 0
create() {

        game.tempGameScore = game.preferences.getInteger("Save");
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your code and the comment seem disjointed. Why are you doing a getInteger("Save"), that doesn't line up with your code of putInteger("score").

In create(), you initialize your preferences, that is fine:

```
game.preferences =  Gdx.app.getPreferences(Drop.PREFS_NAME);
```

But your get/put need to line up. They work like a hashmap, so you have to use the same key.

```
game.tempGameScore = game.preferences.getInteger("score");
```

Then later, to "save":

```
game.preferences.putInteger("score", game.tempGameScore);
game.preferences.flush();
```

Comment: i updated the code
look, varible game.tempGameScore saved in class C, all good,if i close  the app  and  start app again in class C game.tempGameScore = 0. Variable game.tempGameScore doesn't save last score

Comment: Not sure, with all your code fragments, could be you are not executing in the order you think you are. Maybe work backward, create a simple barebones app and make sure you can put/get values. Are you sure the put is getting called with a non zero value? Did you open the saved file after you've done your put to make sure the value is actually being written, so perhaps it is a read issue, etc.

Comment: @ Peter R
And what is the default folder where to write SETTINGS?

Comment: depends on the OS. Check out the doc (near bottom) https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

Comment: @ Peter R
in android ~/.prefs/My Preferences?

Comment: Sorry, think I've contributed all I can with suggestions and pointed you to the doc/other sample code. Maybe someone else will jump in.

Comment: This example from the documentation work, but why it is not saved after the close the application and opened